# Inconsistent border width between table rows after collapsing the cell border

Tags: html, css, html-table, border, border-layout

I'm having the issue that my table borders act differently after collapsing it.
[image]

It seems the bottom border width of second row is slightly thicker than the rest, I tried changing the border style but still couldn't identify the issue.
Here is my code:

```css
table {
    background-color: burlywood;
    height: 200px;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table > tbody > tr > td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>cell 1</td>
            <td>cell 2</td>
            <td>cell 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cell 4</td>
            <td>cell 5</td>
            <td>cell 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cell 7</td>
            <td>cell 8</td>
            <td>cell 9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cell 10</td>
            <td>cell 11</td>
            <td>cell 12</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My goal is to make all border width consistent, thanks for anyone helping me on this.

Comment: I dont see any difference in my screen! Just in your image I can see the difference!

Comment: hmm then I guess it might my browser problems, anyway thanks for answering